# How to Upload a file from web to android web server using NanoHttp

Tags: android, http, nanohttpd

I need to use android device as web server and browser as client.

I need to be able to upload file from client to android device, I really don't know how.
I really don't understand anything from Http stuff and nano.

Comment: And where is your client running? `need to be able to upload file from client  `And that file is somewhere on the web?

Comment: @blackapps as I said, web page on browser.

Comment: ??? You did not talk about a web page. Then where is your/that browser running?

Comment: @blackapps another device on the network

Comment: Which network? I have a network too you know. And on which network is nanohttpd? And explain about that web page and about that file. It's all so unclear.